How can I combine multiple functions into one to make a connected graph?
I tried this in desmos:
$$
f\left(x\right)=\left(\left(x+6\right)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{-2-x}}{\sqrt{-2-x}}\right)+\left(x^{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}}\right)+\left(\left(\frac{x}{2}+3\right)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x-2}}\right)
$$
I initially thought, from $-\infty$ to $-2$, it'd draw $x+6$ due to the last two terms cancelling out and being zero, then from $-2$ to $2$ it'd draw $x^2$ as the other two terms are cancelled out to zero, and $\frac{x}{2}+3$ from $2$ to $\infty$.

But it just created a blank graph.

I realized the function returns undefined for all domains of x $[-\infty, \infty]$. So, how do I make this work? How would I create such function that will draw this graph?
And also a follow-up question: if such function exists, I reckon the values at $-2$ and $2$ will be undefined because the function is only valid in $\{x<-2, -2<x<2, x>2\}$. So how can such function be redefined so that $x$ values of $-2$ and $2$ aren't left out?

Use either a piece-wise function or indicator functions.

Use a piece-wise function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x+6, & \text{for }x < -2; \\ x^2, & \text{for } -2 \leq x < 2; \\ \tfrac x 2 +3, & \text{for } x \geq 2. \end{cases}$$
Or use indicator functions. An indicator function over a set $A$ returns 1 for values of $x$ inside of $A$ and 0 elsewhere:
$$I_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } x \in A; \\ 0, & \text{otherwhise.} \end{cases}$$
Then, use indicator functions over each of your intervals, and scale them accordingly with the segmented graphs you want to put together:
$$f(x) = (x+6) \, I_{\{x < -2\}} (x) +x^2 \, I_{\{-2 \leq x < 2\}} (x) +(\tfrac x 2 +3) \, I_{\{x \geq 2\}} (x).$$
It is a good practice to make sure the intervals don’t overlap, specially at the endpoints; but since your segmented graphs seem to be equal wherever they met (verifying this yourself is also a good practice), it may not make any difference.

Thank you for the answer! Just another question: How can I implement this in Desmos?

After messing around, I finally got
$$
f\left(x\right)=\left{x<-2:\ 2x+8,\ -2\le x<2:\ x^{2},\ x\ge2:\ \frac{x}{2}+3\right}
$$
Thank you very much!
